# Как позвонить от имени бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Я написал телеграм бота тех. поддержки, где администратор общается с пользователями от имени бота.

**Как добавить звонки от имени бота?**

Чтобы администратор смог позвонить пользователю и смог с ним общаться через телеграм.

Comment: Нашёл только функционал проигрывания аудиофайла.

Comment: Это невозможно в рамках обычного Telegram Bot'а, но это возможно используя клиентскую часть приложения и реализация данного бота как пользователя Telegram. например через [tgcalls](https://github.com/MarshalX/tgcalls) и [PyTgCalls](https://github.com/pytgcalls/pytgcalls)

Comment: Если правильно понял, бота нужно переписать на Pyrogram?